# answering a question with additional info

Tags: discussion, answers

I answered a question about a form being submitted on a website with php. The user stated he was new to php.

I put  a lot of effort into making it a simple as possible for him, but with thorough explanation. I also suggested a spamcheck in php and that he could validate the data with javascript.

I got slammmed by another user, who downvoted my question and said it was most unhelpful, all over the place.

I replied in comment

> NO it's NOT the OP is asking for help with a form in his website, he has STATED he doesn't know much about php, so I am offering him advise to PROTECT the whole process of submitting the form through php, and advising there are other option to help this process, SORRY it annoys you so, I understand beginners and try to help

[PHP Contact Form Not Sending Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929257/php-contact-form-not-sending-email)

I find this frustrating, as I am making a genuine effort to help someone and think that this feedback is just rude and non-constructive. It s worded in a way that I cannot make a flag.

Is my answer poor? Is it a bad answer to cover some areas about the process the OP is seeking advice for?

Comment: Personally, I agree the answer was a bit far-reaching, and your snarkiness regarding the other commenter's tag ranks was out of line, unrelated to anything, and a knee-jerk reaction because you were sad you got downvoted. You didn't do yourself any favors: I guess maybe if you feel new, and uncomfortable because of your gender, maybe be more receptive to criticism, and not react by lashing out.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes I apologised to Steve for my sarkiness.. I am too reactive (and there are gender differences- women's mood fluctuate more - physiological fact ) I've studied medical science, should go to a forum on that! ha

Comment: If I wasn't bipolar and ADHD I might let the gender-based generalization slide, but please keep in the back of your head that you never really know who you're talking to, why they're reacting the way they are, and that a downvote isn't necessarily a reaction to you-as-a-person but rather precisely what it is: a downvote on a question or answer, and nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a bad answer to cover some areas about the process the OP is
>   seeking advice for?

In general, it's good to cover things that might be useful to the OP (tempered with common sense).

I'm guessing you were downvoted for several reasons:

- The question isn't that great...mediocre questions represent a moving target, namely, there isn't necessarily a correct answer.
- It's hard to find the actual solution in your answer to the OP's problem. Like the OP, I'm a PHP novice, and the extras in the answer distracted me until I reread the answer a few times.
- Your terminology is a little off (personally, I wouldn't downvote that). An HTML form "submits", not "links" or "directs".
- The answer may be factually wrong (judging from the comments). Right or wrong, people are free to downvote an answer they feel is incorrect.
- The extended discussion in the comments over the merits/demerits of w3schools.com probably didn't help anyone's mood.

Downvotes happen. Use it as an opportunity for a personal audit, and either determine how you would do better in the future or conclude that you were in the right.

I've had both experiences and I can safely say that downvotes are sometimes completely unwarranted. But sometimes you can learn a thing or two.

Comment: yes thank you for your answer. I started the answer gracefully and then as other answers came I got stressed and rushed it.. hm I think that is also a key, my best answers are to less popular questions where I can take my time. And yes I shouldn't have used the word link in that way.. is it still ok for me to edit and improve my answer.. ps my php in the answer works

Comment: Sure, you can continue to improve your answer. And I completely understand rushing as you see other answers coming in. It's hard to let other people get those first upvotes, but a good answer is its own reward.

Answer (score 2):

Primarily, I think the reason for the downvoting was that your answer contained Javascript, when the question clearly didn't ask about anything related to Javascript. Plus, that code seems rather superfluous.

While I don't know enough about PHP, HTML, or Javascript to comment on your syntax, it seems from the comments like your OP had errors in it. Syntax errors are a valid reason to downvote.

Additionally, from the question itself:

> Please take a look at my code below (PHP is not my thing) and let me know where i've gone wrong.

Your answer doesn't really address the user's code specifically, nor the errors in it. Your answer instead answers something rather different, though I'm not quite sure what.

It's best to stick to the languages the OP is asking about, and stick to specifically what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Yvette I can't force you to, but I urge you to at least _consider_ that your answer was unhelpful. Coming to Meta saying "this person is out of line" requires you to be willing to consider the opposite.

Comment: @Yvette It's not up to me to decide if you're a worthwhile member - that's up to you. I firmly hold that each member of StackOverflow has the potential to be a contributing member; some need more experience, others need more time, etc. So I'm not going to decide for you if you want to leave. I acknowledge that being both new to code and helpful to new programmers is difficult, but I don't think I would tell anyone to stop trying.

Comment: @Yvette And you fact to people you think are out of line by being snarky, bringing up irrelevant tag ranks, and so on? Is that likely to be the best approach? Steve is welcome to downvote for what seem to be valid reasons. If you believe his comments are out of line, flag them for moderator attention. They didn't seem to be, but I'll re- read them.

Comment: @Yvette IMO no, it doesn't explain things. Sounds like it might be more worthwhile, and fulfilling, to focus on your answers and progress than someone else's reactions and comments to them/it.

Comment: @Yvette I think maybe you might consider taking a step back and reflect on why you're on SO and what specifically you want to accomplish here. We cannot control, and sometimes can't even influence, how others react to our presence here and in the world. Recognizing we can only control *our* reactions might be important to keep in mind.

Comment: I delete my comments, I don't think are suitable for this site